# Permission for adding files in shared folder without delete permission

Tags: permissions

I want to add files in shared folder but I must not be able to delete files in that folder, so which permission is required?

Modify - also allows to delete
Read - Can't add files as I know.

Comment: Please add to what OS you're referring _(in question, not comment)_

Comment: You might want to setup a backup method for that folder because modifying any file requires deleting the original one for the new one. Moving it requires the same operations.

Comment: As specified by CaldeiraG using a backup would allow you to give modify permissions to users (Obviously the backup type and frequency would be dependant on how transient the data is.). Another approach would be to create a second folder as an intermediary. Give modify permissions to the new folder and write a script that can be executed by a user with write permissions to the second folder so that the file placed in folder one can be moved to folder two periodically (I would suggest putting in the script - a test if file already exists and append something to the name if file already exists).

Comment: Please note, if using Windows shared folders both top level *share* permissions and *file* level permissions come into play with the most restrictive winning.